# MYSQL Insert date today with specific format query

Tags: mysql, date

Hi I want to insert a data into table with the date today with a specific date format. My date in column is set to like `dd-mm-yyyy` but i want to insert a date in literal form like `28 October 2016`

I know how to insert the current date today and also know how to select date with specific format but I'm having a little confusion with combining this two queries

For inserting current date:

```
INSERT INTO product_table(product_names, product_type,product_brand,product_price,product_count,product_note, product_date) VALUES ('Logitech','Mouse','Sample',100,5,'1 year warranty',CURRENT_DATE)
```

For selecting with specific date format

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(product_date, %d %M %Y) from product_table;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a date in a column as `28 October 2016`, you'll need to make it a `VARCHAR` field or something.

If that's the case, I don't why you'd want to insert it like that, rather than just format it on the way out of the database?

Comment: I need to make it in DATE format because I have a module in my system that will need to deduct the date like showing last month. and many more.

Comment: @MaryJhealynVillena if you need DATE column, you must format it like `YYYY-MM-DD` - there is no other option as far as i know.